# Provide called shell script with input in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I have a python program which uses various Bash shell scripts. However, some of them require (y/n) input. I know the input required based on the question number so it's a matter of being able to provide that automatically.

Is there a way in Python to do that?

As a last resort I can send a signal to a window etc. but I'd rather not do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the the easiest way is to use [pexpect](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pexpect/). An example (from the [overview](http://www.noah.org/wiki/Pexpect#Overview) in the wiki):

```
import pexpect

child = pexpect.spawn('ftp ftp.openbsd.org')
child.expect('Name .*: ')
child.sendline('anonymous')
child.expect('Password:')
child.sendline('noah@example.com')
child.expect('ftp> ')
child.sendline('cd pub')
child.expect('ftp> ')
child.sendline('get ls-lR.gz')
child.expect('ftp> ')
child.sendline('bye')
```

If you don't want to use an extra module, using `subprocess.Popen` is the way to go, but it is more complicated. First you create the process.

```
import subprocess

script = subprocess.Popen(['script.sh'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                          stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

You can either use `shell=True` here, or prepend the name of the shell to the command arguments. The former is easier.

Next you need to read from `script.stdout` until you find your question number. Then you write the answer to `script.stdin`.

Comment: `shell=True` is considered unsafe.

Comment: Almost. It is unsafe _with untrusted input_. But the alternative of prepending the name of the shell to the args list is _equally_ unsafe in that case. If you want to run a shell script, you're going to have to use a shell...

Comment: Note that some password prompts will bypass stdin to read directly from the controlling terminal. In those cases, you can't give them the password with a pipe, but it's still possible using pexpect.

Answer (score 3):

Use `subprocess.Popen`.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE


popen = Popen(command, stdin=PIPE)
popen.communicate('y')
```

Comment: This answer won't work it its current form, since you also have to read the "question number" from the process's standard output.

Comment: If that's so, then one must do nasty pipe rw.