# No input box in VS Code Jupyter Notebook for shell command

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, ipython, vscode-extensions

While running a command in IPython notebook which needs user input, there is no space provided to give terminal input.
Is there any way to resolve this?

(I tried to write `!pip3 uninstall pandas`, but it got stuck at "Proceed (Y/n)?")

[image]

Comment: possibly related: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/4572, https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/514, https://stackoverflow.com/q/18907103/11107541

Answer (score 1):

Jupyter notebooks have a limitation when running shell commands that they don't take input. When running pip commands, it's suggested to use `%` instead of `!`, and to pass `-y`, like `%pip install <package> -y` ([source](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/4572#issuecomment-1600263513)).

Comment: I know I can pass -y but I wanted to give input in the text box

Comment: @anuja and I have answered that question at the very top of this answer post, _and_ added a link to the source of the information.